TypeScript cannot un-narrowing of type of variable even going passing await expression that mutate the variable
I was implementing a cancel mechanism for a long-run asynchronous function (A.a in the code example below).
class A {
    state: 'running' | 'stopped'
    constructor() {
        this.state = 'stopped'
    }
    async a() {
        this.state = 'running'
        for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            console.log(`i: ${i}`)
            if (this.state === 'stopped') {
                return
            }
            await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve();
                }, 1000)
            })
        }
    }
}

const a = new A();

(async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        a.state = 'stopped'
    }, 5000)
    await a.a();
    console.log('finished')
})();

On TypeScript Playground it reports an error on the line if (this.state === 'stopped'):

This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"running"' and '"stopped"' have no overlap.

I kinda know that TypeScript narrows types on if-else expression, etc, but if I'm understanding correctly, the value of the expression being "narrowed" on might be altered during the execution of a await-expression, because it will execute any code that the scheduler want to.
I have tried a few solutions to this, including:

Using enum for type of the state field.
Adding getter and setter to get/set the state field.

but neither of the two solutions solve the problem.
I'm expecting the type-checker let me pass, but I'm more curious what is a more proper way to implement logic like this, i.e. implement a custom canceller for a long-run promise.

This seems like a limitation in the type checker, where it assumes that the local state will not be updated during the method execution.
Take this case:
function foo(a?: number) {
    if (a) {
        0 + a;
    }
}

The type-checker here no longer complains about a being possibly unset, because it was validated to be present in the if-statement.
In your case, it is assuming that the value for this.state is reduced to only 'running', because you specifically set it to that literal.
To get around this, you can simply cast to the union type instead.
this.state = 'running' as 'running' | 'stopped'

In case you need to do this many times, define the value separately.
type State = 'running' | 'stopped'

class A {
    state: State
    constructor() {
        this.state = 'stopped'
    }
    async a() {
        this.state = 'running' as State
        for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            console.log(`i: ${i}`)
            if (this.state === 'stopped') {
                return
            }
            await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve();
                }, 1000)
            })
        }
    }
}

